How to remove the large left and right paddings due to "lines+markers" lines?
How to remove the large left and right paddings due to "lines+markers" lines?
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

count = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": np.random.randint(10, 20, size=(count)),
        "B": np.random.randint(10, 20, size=(count)),
        "C": np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(count)),
    },
    index=[f"bar.{i}" for i in range(count)],
)

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name=df.columns[0],
            orientation="v",
            x=df.index,
            y=df.iloc[:, 0],
            text=df.iloc[:, 0],
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name=df.columns[1],
            orientation="v",
            x=df.index,
            y=df.iloc[:, 1],
            text=df.iloc[:, 1],
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            name=df.columns[2],
            x=df.index,
            y=df.iloc[:, 2],
            text=df.iloc[:, 2],
            mode="lines+markers",
        ),
    ],
    layout=dict(
        width=1024,
        height=512,
        margin=dict(l=10, r=10, t=10, b=10),
    ),
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=None,
    yaxis_title=None,
    legend_title=None,
)

fig.show()


If I don't set the mode or reduce the data point count from 100 to 10, I can get rid of the large paddings:


This is a similar issue to the one in this question: How to remove the large top and bottom paddings due to top-to-bottom lines?

Just like this answer, we can set the range of the X axis to remove the large paddings.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

count = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": np.random.randint(10, 20, size=(count)),
        "B": np.random.randint(10, 20, size=(count)),
        "C": np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(count)),
    },
    index=[f"bar.{i}" for i in range(count)],
)

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name=df.columns[0],
            orientation="v",
            x=df.index,
            y=df.iloc[:, 0],
            text=df.iloc[:, 0],
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name=df.columns[1],
            orientation="v",
            x=df.index,
            y=df.iloc[:, 1],
            text=df.iloc[:, 1],
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            name=df.columns[2],
            x=df.index,
            y=df.iloc[:, 2],
            text=df.iloc[:, 2],
            mode="lines+markers",
        ),
    ],
    layout=dict(
        width=1024,
        height=512,
        margin=dict(l=10, r=10, t=10, b=10),
    ),
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=None,
    yaxis_title=None,
    legend_title=None,
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[count - 0.5, 0 - 0.5],
    ),
)

fig.show()


